# Whats the name of the css technique material design lite (google) implements?

Tags: css, performance, web, frontend, pagespeed

I heard, but cannot find any document to double check, that this technique helps reduce the computer processes with specificity of CSS, when the browser has to calculate which class to apply when a tag has IDs or Classes in the document.

This is an extract from Google Material Design Lite, which uses the technique such:

```
<!-- Colored FAB button -->
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--colored">  
<i class="material-icons">add</i>
</button>
```

You will notice the class

```
mdl-button
```

This one is used as an ID basically. While

```
mdl-button--colored
```

is the ID mentioned above, with the class

```
colored
```

So, practically this is the same to:

```
#mdl-button.colored
```

With the difference that the computer wont have to process the specificity with the ID and Class, because now we only have a unique class.

So again.. the question is **"how is this technique called"** or if there is no name, maybe can someone post a link to documents that explain deeply the concept?

Cheers guys!

Comment: No.. `mdl-button--colored` is a class not an ID...it's an entirely separate class that has it's own distinct styling. It's all part of BEM/SMACSS methodology.

Comment: So it's not `#mdl-button.colored` it's `.mdl-button.mdl-button--colored` which is a differently level of specificity,

Comment: Yes, I know it is a class. The technique speaks about using classes as IDs.
that's why the `.mdl-button` acts like the unique identifier and then adding the `--colored` makes it even more specific.

Comment: Classes are not unique identifiers, they are group identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out the Block Element Modifier methodology for CSS. The idea behind it helps you achieve reusable components and code sharing in the front-end.

[image: BEM CSS]

Check out this link for more information:

http://getbem.com/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

descendant, child or adjacent, and overly qualified selectors

Which are what Google says not to use.